# Difference between Facebook login behaviour using Appcelerator/ titanium/ alloy

Tags: android, ios, facebook, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am using appcelerator's Facebook module: https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.facebook

However, it's quite poorly documented.

My question is what's the difference between the following Facebook login behaviours (https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.facebook#facebook-login-and-authorization):

- LOGIN_BEHAVIOR_BROWSER
- LOGIN_BEHAVIOR_NATIVE
- LOGIN_BEHAVIOR_SYSTEM_ACCOUNT (iOS only)
- LOGIN_BEHAVIOR_WEB (iOS only)
- LOGIN_BEHAVIOR_NATIVE_WITH_FALLBACK (Android only - NATIVE will attempt to fallback on iOS)
- LOGIN_BEHAVIOR_DEVICE_AUTH (Android only)

There's seems to be no explanation or screenshots in what any of these do.

I understand the browser one, but the NATIVE, SYSTEM_ACCOUNT and 
NATIVE_WITH_FALLBACK all seem to do the same thing (only tested on ios).

Answer (score 2):

LOGIN_BEHAVIOR_BROWSER :
Opens login window in the default Web Browser.

LOGIN_BEHAVIOR_NATIVE :
Opens login window with the native Facebook app. On iOS it will attempt to fallback to if the Facebook app is not installed or Facebook chooses it internally. For Android use to get this behavior.

LOGIN_BEHAVIOR_SYSTEM_ACCOUNT :
Attempts to login with through the Facebook account currently signed in through Settings.

LOGIN_BEHAVIOR_WEB :
Opens login window through a modal browser window.

LOGIN_BEHAVIOR_NATIVE_WITH_FALLBACK :
Opens login window with the native Facebook app. On Android it will attempt to fallback to if the Facebook app is not installed. For iOS use to get this behavior.

LOGIN_BEHAVIOR_DEVICE_AUTH :
Expose Facebook Login for devices such as Android TV and Fire TV.

Comment: I don't understnd `LOGIN_BEHAVIOR_NATIVE_WITH_FALLBACK`. What do you mean "For iOS use to get this behaviour." Also whats the difference between that and `LOGIN_BEHAVIOR_NATIVE`. Out of curiosity where did you find this information?

Comment: About LOGIN_BEHAVIOR_NATIVE from facebook SDK 4.11.0 seems to not allow logging in using the Facebook app to login.so no need to use it anymore and you can find a discussion here."https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/786729821439894/?search_id"